# Firebase RealTimeDatabase Query gives snapshot with no values

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with a query, I want to get data between first day of the week and the last and for that I have converted the dates to milliseconds. But there are no values in the snapshot. Does someone know what I did wrong?

I have checked and there is at least one millisecond amount thats between the two dates(first and last). The milliseconds have been saved as a double.

I have posted part of my code below and the database.

```
referenceIncome = database.getReference("/users");
```

```
double firstDateWeek = firstDate.get(Integer.parseInt(current));
double endDateWeek = endDate.get(Integer.parseInt(current));

Query query = referenceIncome.child(userID).child("Money").orderByChild("millisecond").startAt(firstDateWeek).endAt(endDateWeek);

query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
```

---

```
{
  "users" : {
    "8ps1o0nA95bRr1aMKDwnXQEoZxA3" : {
      "Money" : {
        "17-01-2021" : {
          "-MRG-KinX5n6_MflOqm8" : {
            "date" : "17-01-2021",
            "id" : "-MRG-KinX5n6_MflOqm8",
            "millisecond" : 1610898037725,
            "money" : 800,
            "spendOrEarn" : "Expenses",
            "type" : "groceries"
          },
          "-MRGX-Qhm2383hNRTKc6" : {
            "date" : "17-01-2021",
            "id" : "-MRGX-Qhm2383hNRTKc6",
            "millisecond" : 1610906863156,
            "money" : 77,
            "spendOrEarn" : "Expenses",
            "type" : "groceries"
          },
          "-MRGX1cG87WLK-KcaKl-" : {
            "date" : "17-01-2021",
            "id" : "-MRGX1cG87WLK-KcaKl-",
            "millisecond" : 1610906872152,
            "money" : 3456,
            "spendOrEarn" : "Expenses",
            "type" : "groceries"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a query on `/users/$uid/Money`. This means that Firebase takes the child nodes directly under that location and:

1. Orders them on their `millisecond` property.
2. Then returns only the slice that you indicate with `startAt` and `endAt`.

The problem is that the **direct** child node under `/users/$uid/Money` is `/users/$uid/Money/17-01-2021` and that node does not have a `millisecond` property.

Firebase queries work on a flat list of direct child node, so if you want to query the Money nodes by user: store them as a flat list directly under `/users/$uid/Money`, instead of grouping them by date.